# How efficient is multi-channel fan controller over individually stepped down fans?

Tags: power-supply, fan, desktop-computer

Suppose I have a decent fan controller with 4 channels.
I have four identical 12v fans set to run at 12v, 9v, 7v and 5v respectively.

On the other hand, I am using resistors to step down voltage and have same fans running at same voltages. Obviously this means that the voltages are no longer variable.

How does energy loss vary between the two? Is the fan controller more efficient?

Comment: Is this a pratical question? Sounds like homework

Comment: It is for my setup. I have a few 12V devices on my table (Fiber modem, Router, Gigabit switch, HDD Dock, USB Hub). To maximize efficiency, I am powering everything using a single 12V 12.5A Adapter. I would also like to add fans to the same adapter so want to minimize energy loss with fan controller.

Answer (score 1):

The fan controller would use a DC-DC converter or a PWM circuit to cut down the voltage.

A resistor uses Ohm's law to cut down the voltage, but in the mean time, generates a lot of heat. How much heat is generated seems like a good homework exercise ;)

For all practical applications, go with the fan controller.

Comment: Fan controller it is then. Furthermore, if I am running 3 fans all at 7v, would there be any difference if I use a multi-channel controller vs a higher amp single channel?

P.S.: This ain't homework. I intend to run all fans at same selected speed (variable) so a higher amp (2A maybe) single channel fan controller is what I need. However, there is a very good multi channel one on auction on eBay so I wanna make sure if won't be any less efficient than a single channel solution.